# Windows kernel driver for direct I/O - anyone been there?

Tags: windows, driver, port, parallel-processing

I need to handle direct I/O to a parallel port in a better way that we are doing it at the moment - presently we use a kernel driver that 'opens up' useable addresses using the I/O protection map. This works ok but is getting more and more left behind. We still wish to continue using a parallel port and there are very satisfactory parallel port card vendors for CardBus ExpressCard etc. I'd like to create a driver that knew about the address assigned to the device by the bus enumerator and allowed me to write to this address from my (Delphi) app. Due to the appernt complexity of this topic I'm struggling with where to start. Has anyone been this route please?

Comment: Have you considered/rejected using the usual Win32 API to talk to the standard parallel port driver?

Answer (score 1):

You might try `inoutp32.dll`.
Please visit:

http://sheepdogguides.com/dt4j.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may try the WinIO library on [www.internals.com](http://www.internals.com/)